# telerik reporting with mvc 3 example

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, telerik-reporting

I am creating the MVC3 application, where i am suppose to implement the Telerik reporting. 
I struggled a lot, some time dll registration problem, final rendering the report on view is the most difficult for me.

i have fond the answer and that's down here.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.telerik.com/community/code-library/reporting/general/using-telerik-web-reportviewer-in-asp-net-mvc-application.aspx

Here is the url which describe the output.